# iOS — Determining whether Accelerate.framework is available at runtime

Tags: c++, iphone, c, ios

Is there any way to determine whether the Accelerate.framework is available at runtime *from straight C or C++* files?

The examples I've found for conditional coding all seem to require Objective-C introspection (e.g., `respondsToSelector`) and/or Objective-C apis (e.g., UIDevice's `systemVersion` member)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual trick for this is that you *weak link* against the framework and then check a function pointer exported by that framework for the actual availability. If the framework failed to link because it is not available then the function will be `NULL`.

So for `Accelerate.framework` you would do something like this:

```
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

if (cblas_sdsdot) {
    NSLog(@"Yay we got Accelerate.framework");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Oh no, no Accelerate.framework");
}
```

This is described in [TN2064 - Ensuring Binary Backwards Compatibility](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2064.html#SECTION2)

Comment: Ah, and the availability macros automatically handle the weak-linking. So simple! Thanks!

Comment: You also need to mark the framework as weak-linked in Xcode (target -> your target, sort by "role", change the right one to weak). Also note that you need to stick a & beside weak-linked symbols if they're not functions (e.g. UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification), so it's possibly a better idea to just always use a &.